# Informational messages in python unit testing

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm using Python's [`unittest`](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html) module for unit testing.

I'd like to be able to report informational messages as part of the unit test output—other than pass/fail status. Specifically in my case, I want to report whether the module under test is using the pure Python implementation or the C extension.

Is there a mechanism in [`unittest`](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html) to output informational messages as part of the test report? Can it be done in alternative Python unit test frameworks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't aware of nosetests and it might make sense to use that plugin for a variety of reasons. I would use the [logging](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) module myself.

Comment: Do you know of any existing Python projects you could point us to, which use that method?

Comment: Sorry Craig, I don't know of a project off-hand. Have you used logging before? It's super flexible in terms of output. Throw up some sample code and we'll work it.

Comment: Now I've tried out logging, and it's super useful. I hadn't thought of using it in unit tests in this way. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use [nosetests](http://somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose), which has a plugin system which allows this. For example the [TestResult](http://somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose/0.11.3/api/result.html) api allows to provide extended reporting:

> Provides a TextTestResult that extends unittest’s _TextTestResult to provide support for error classes (such as the builtin skip and deprecated classes), and hooks for plugins to take over or extend reporting.